# Should we return and then print the result or just print the result inside the function?

Tags: python-3.x

A beginner here.

I have a simple query. Following are two ways of using a cube function(in Python 3.9) to get the desired output.

```
def cube(x):
    return x*x*x


print(cube(5))
```

or

```
def cube(x):
    print(x*x*x)

cube(5)
```

both of these blocks will produce 125 as an output, but which one is more preferable according to your own point of view.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the top one. When possible functions should be kept as independent as possible, so you can reuse the code in different places, so returning a value is always preferable.

Say for example (very simple example which has other solutions but just to demonstrate) you then wanted to write a function which takes a number to its 6th power. Well, with the bottom example of the `cube` function you would have to just write out the whole function, but with the top example, you can do this:

```
def sixth_power(x):
    cubed = cube(x)
    return cubed * cubed
```

So hopefully you can see that having the code be reusable is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I got it now :) Have a nice day sir!!